Which webpack hooks can hooking into dynamic import
I write a webpack plugin which collect informations of import. I use parser.hooks.import hooking into import statement like import xxx from 'xxx'. but for dynamic import like const yy = import('yy'). is there a hook can hooking it.
I try parser.hooks.call.for('import') and parser.hooks.expression.for('import')， but they don't works. which hooks should i use??
